# Angular - Animation between pages (after changing route)

Tags: animation, angular, angular2-routing

I'm still new to Angular 2 and was wondering if there is a way to let a component 'fly in' and let another component 'fly out' when switching routes. Let's say I have 2 components: Test1Component and Test2Component and 2 routes pointing to each of them. What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9845#issuecomment-235799008

> RC5 will hopefully be out this week, if not then next week.
>
> For now (with RC5) you will need to do this for **every component** that
>   is routed to and you want to add animations to:
>
> ```
> @Component({
>    host: {
>      '[@routeAnimation]': 'true'
>    },
>    animations: [
>       trigger('routeAnimation', [
>          transition('* => void', animate(...)),
>          transition('void => *', animate(...))
>       ])
>    ]
> })
> class Cmp { }
> ```
>
> Once we get `query()` and `$variables` into animations then you can use
>   `<router-outlet>` with the URL API that I wrote above.

Comment: Thank you, but  can you tell me how to bind it properly? It's giving me this error: "Can't bind to '@routeAnimation' since it isn't a known native property".

Comment: I haven't tried animations myself yet. Did you check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html?