# How do I use Angular2 (RC5) routeAnimation?

Tags: animation, angular, angular2-routing

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38628793/angular-2-animation-between-pages-after-changing-route) post, but when I use it, my component just appears below the new one and then disappears.
What should I put in animate? I tried stuff like

```
animate(300, keyframes([
    style({opacity: 1}),
    style({opacity: 0})
]))
```

But it didn't work at all (same as just something like animate('300ms')).

How should I set the animation type if it's not inside animate?

Is there any documentation on this already? The 'Animations' page in the official website is awfully incomplete.

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

I solved it partially by applying the *display: block* style to my animations, which I did kind of like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37909208/angular-2-slide-in-animation-of-a-routed-component). I still can't make the new route properly wait for the previous route animation to end. Both appear at the same time even if I delay the animation (the space is already taken).